# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.ICorsService

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I observe an exception executing the following code:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =                         
    WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)
        .ConfigureServices(Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices)
        .Build()
```

Error:

> Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.ICorsService

Details:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.ICorsService' while
>   attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware'.'

I added the Cors code here:

```
let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication() |> ignore
    services.AddCors |> ignore // Enables CORS
```

Note:

This all use to work until I added ASP.Net WebAPI support for some json that I was struggling with.

In addition, I also upgraded my Nuget packages to 2.0.

The source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Server/Nikeza.Server/Program.fs).

Comment: I might be off, but I don't see where you are using `AddMvc` and `UseMvc` in `Startup.fs`

Comment: Hi Camilio, The service was running before without those lines you suggested.

Comment: What specifically did you add "until I added ASP.NET WebAPI support..."? WebAPI does not exist on ASP.NET Core, just so you know.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim

Answer (score 64):

You have to add `services.AddCors()` in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`